# ReactJS: How can I align form <Field>'s <input> and <button> and <h1> in a row inside a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have `<button/>` and `<input/>` inside a container. How can I get them to align in the same row, next to each other, and in the middle of the container vertically?

This is what I have so far:

[image]

The top black portion is a navigation bar and I want to side-by-side align them in a row, next to each other from left to right, and align them vertically in the middle of the navigation bar:

**PLEASE TAKE A LOOK AT EDIT AT THE BOTTOM FOR UPDATED CODE**

```
       import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

       const form = reduxForm({
         form: 'register'
       });

       ...

  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
       <div className="container">
        <h1>
          TESTING
        </h1>
        <form>
            <Field
              name="email"
              className="form-control"
              component={
                  <div>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      id="input-field"
                      placeholder='Enter Email'
                    />
                 </div>
              }
              type="text"
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn"
            >
              Register
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```

And CSS stylesheet:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: black;
  }
header h1#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: purple;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#input-field {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Decided to take the Form out but CSS stay the same. How can I flex align the following to achieve what I originally wanted (Would like to have the h1 to the left and text field + button to the right?

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
       <div className="container">
          <h1>
            TESTING
          </h1>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            id="input-field"
            placeholder='Enter Email'
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn"
          >
            Register
          </button>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This is how you do this with the `flex` property.

Also, be sure to replace all the `className` in HTML with `class`. Be sure to style your `input` and `button` according to your likings.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
h1,
.btn,
#input-field {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>
            TESTING
          </h1>
      <input class="form-control" id="input-field" placeholder='Enter Email' />
      <button type="submit" class="btn">
        Register
      </button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

> Although `table` elements should not be used for aligning elements
>   next to each other(they are meant for storing tabular data), using
>   `table`s is indeed a working solution to your problem.
>
> -- Yash Jain --

[Here is a live example on a JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zachzw3/) with your exact same elements.

So don't say in the comments that `table`s should not be used for formatting, since I **CLEARLY** stated it.

And this code is 100% **GUARANTEED** to work, because you can't override a `table` in CSS despite whatever code you have.

Take a look at this code snippet first.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div className="container">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h1>
            TESTING
          </h1>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input className="form-control" id="input-field" placeholder='Enter Email' />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="submit" className="btn">
                Register
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry before I accept the answer, could you show a working example with the code that I provided? Because I tried something similar before and in real practice didn't work..

Comment: thanks saw it but I meant with < h1 > TESTING < h1 > as well. But just like any typical navigation bar, I would want the h1 to be on the left side and text field with button on the right side, and space between the h1 and textfield/button

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Please let me know so I go accept the answer and upvote. I actually updated the original post with EDIT and took out Form cause it seemed too hacky to align them. How can I display: flex align the newly updated code with what I originally hoped for?

Comment: I looked at the edit now, please check the revised code.

Comment: I am trying to do one with flex but still no luck. Could you show with the flex?

Comment: I did it with the flex above.